# MVC: Model is null in a view's aspx

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm following this [MVC tutorial](http://www.asp.net/learn/mvc/tutorial-21-cs.aspx) and when I add a View for the Edit action, Model is null in the following snippet on the .aspx page:

```
<%= Html.TextBox("Id", Model.Id) %>
```

I'm learning MVC, so please understand if I'm doing a dumb thing. But as far as I can see, I've following the steps in the tutorial pretty well. And actually added the Create action and it works correctly.

Ideas appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is your view strongly typed?

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/TwoColumnUI.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<MyObject>" %>
```

then you would need to pass in an object of type MyObject from your controller action method

```
return View(new MyObject() { Id = 42 } );
```

Comment: Thank you, worked.

        public ActionResult Edit(int id)
        {
            return View(new Movies() { Id = id });
        }

Comment: Note: You don't HAVE to use the anonymous constructor.

Comment: This is not an anonymous constructor but an object initializer syntax in C# 3.0... And yes, I know it's not a necessary condition, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Did you set the model in the controller? What does your controller method look like?  Are you just returning View()?  You need to pass the model as a parameter to that call like they do in the example:

`return View(movieToEdit);`